# Old laptop screen on tablet

Tags: lcd

I have a laptop that is working but one of the hinges is broken, I have a android tablet, is it possible to detach laptop screen and attache it to the tablet and get the tablet screen on laptop screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask, then probably not. The lcd displays often have some kind of standard interface, which makes it sometimes possible to use it with other hardware. The chance that it will match the interface of the Android is however very unlikely. Because the tablet screen is not a seperate screen, the interface is probably different, and is incorporated in the hardware of the tablet.

The Android software is sometimes capable to adjust to different screen sizes, for example for the HDMI output. But the options are often limited.

If your tablet has a HDMI output, then you can connect screens and projectors to it, but not the bare display of a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may use it by buying a controller for that screen and turning it into monitor or TV will enable you to mirror you android devices screen or may enable you to extend your PCs screen !

Comment: Know you of such a controller?